# java.io.IOException: INVALID_PARAMETERS while implementing Google Cloud Messaging client

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am following the tutorial as [here](http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/):

While my GCM server is implemented, in implementing the GCM client, I get the exception: java.io.IOException: INVALID_PARAMETERS at this line(in the getRegId() in MainActivity as in that tutorial):

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm=GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

My Android manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="raf.rahulserver.com.myapplication" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="raf.rahulserver.com.myapplication.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="raf.rahulserver.com.myapplication.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadCastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="raf.rahulserver.com.myapplication"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It must be noted that the GCM AsyncTask (where that line is in doInBackground()), is an inner class in the activity, so getApplicationContext() is not wrong. Also I tried MainActivity.this instead of getApplicationContext(), still same effect.

So what could I be doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Here is the code which malfunctions as described above:

```
public void getRegId(){
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(PROJECT_NUMBER);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
                    Log.i("GCM",  msg);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();

                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                etRegId.setText(msg + "\n");
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ,

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm=GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
```

Comment: this is an AsyncTask. MainActivity.this already does not work.

Comment: where do you extend the service ?